# can I trade my hat against line numbers (with offset) in SO code samples?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

That would be awesome.

This feature would be a big win for collaboration.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean here?

Comment: The problem with line numbers is that they change when somebody reformats that post. Which is pretty common for questions.

Comment: -1 for abusing winterbash

Comment: I think you're meant to have more to your question than just that...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, we're supposed to avoid editing code in others' posts except for minor fixes.

How would this help collaboration?

Also, many questions get destroyed because there is a big wall of code. I don't think that LOC is a consistent *good* thing, so this may not really be a good hat.

Comment: With the line numbers and especially offset capability it would be easier to reason about small fragments of the code.
But I hadn't thought about editing and reformatting getting all previous comments out of sync. Hmh, a tough nut to crack.